# How to configure refinerycms-calendar engine with the latest Refinerycms 2.1.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

I built a webapp based on RefineryCMS 1.0.3 on 2011 and time has come to have that upgraded.

The webapp is heavily based on refinerycms-calendar engine, which unfortunately its [master branch](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-calendar) is still incompatible with the current RefineryCMS version (2.1.1). Luckily though, there are a couple of folks who have implemented the absolutely necessary to [have that engine functional](https://github.com/danielres/refinerycms-calendar) and I am using that exact version of the engine.

Nevertheless, it still has its issues:

a) Locally the backend works fine but if you try to deploy it with Capistrano, you are missing assets. Apparently, those issues are solved by adding manually `calendar.js` and `calendar.css` into the asset pipeline workflow: Inside your application's `application.rb` add `config.assets.precompile += %w( calendar.js calendar.css )`

b) Fire your Rails server and you will notice that in the frontend, when you click on `Venues` menu item (redirects to `/calendar/venues`) you will receive a complaint that asks for forgiveness: `Page not found Sorry, there was a problem...The page you requested was not found.`. This is caused because there is no actual route to the `venues` controller. But, a `rake routes` reveals that there is one for `/calendar/events/`. Well, this one lands you to another error: `This page is NOT live for public viewing.`. I have not managed to solve this issue yet.

Is there anybody out there having the same problem? Any help greatly appreciated.

Greetings,

Petros